# Animated lines around logo

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a CSS3 animation where I can animate moving lines around the logo starting from the left corner and then ending back there, and the whole border would stay there.

**here is my code:**

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 20s;
}
@keyframes example {
  0% {
    border-left: 10px;
    border-color: black;
  }
  25% {
    border-bottom: 10px;
    border-color: black;
  }
  50% {
    border-right: 10px;
    border-color: black;
  }
  75% {
    border-top: 10px;
    border-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    border: 10px;
    border-color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```

...but it's **not** working. Any ideas?

Comment: hey just look to my answer, you need to add an initial values for `border` and `border-color`...

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996110/progress-bar-along-the-borders-of-a-rectangle/32003052#32003052. Though the question title there is different, the first snippet seems to produce the exact output that you are describing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set a border to start with.. it can't animate something that doesn't exist... just add `border:1px solid black;` to your div code.

If you want it to end on the final frame and retain that style there are 2 other properties needed...

```
animation-iteration-count: 1; // runs animation once
animation-fill-mode: forwards; // keep style specified in last keyframe
```

The final code is as follows:

```css
div {
  border: 0px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    border-left: 10px;
    border-color: black;
  }
  25% {
    border-top: 10px;
    border-color: black;
  }
  50% {
    border-right: 10px;
    border-color: black;
  }
  75% {
    border-bottom: 10px;
    border-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    border: 10px solid black;
    border-color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I disagree. It exactly answers his question. He said his code was not working. I gave him a line of code to add that will make his code work.

Comment: basically I need the border to animate all around the log and the end of animation is a full border

Comment: @TinMonkey then you should add the working code snippet.

Comment: updated to reflect your feedback. working code included.

Comment: yes its close to what I am looking for but I want the last motion only its a little strange right now, its starting by removing the borders, i dont want that I want it to start without borders and then it puts borders from left then bottom then right then top and then shows the whole thing

Comment: I changed it to start with border 0px. Look right now?

Comment: At the start there is a think border that goes really fast and then the animation starts to work right you know why is that

Comment: I think   border: 0; fixed it ,

Comment: border: 0; will break the animation in some browsers... it doesn't work in safari/osx at least.

Comment: yes your right it doesnt work in fiefox , so what to do now

Comment: I believe the code is working as I have it posted.. I think the thin line you are referring to is just the animation starting. maybe try changing the duration to see if it animates smoother?

Comment: ya I hear what your are saying but it looks different i you compare it for chrome and firefox

Comment: That is unfortunately an inherent problem with css. Each browser renders it differently sometimes.. especially this newer css3 stuff. Still somewhat experimental. Javascript may give you more consistent results. I think this question is pretty well answered, even if it turns out the results of css animations are not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I think I need o rethink this in Jquery .animate()

Comment: Would you mind marking as answered then so this one can be wrapped up?