# Animated borders on hover, like "Life of pi" movie website

Tags: html, css, gsap

I was searching for new interactive website ideas early this morning and I saw this website: http://www.lifeofpimovie.com/

If watch the bottom boxes, it's able to animate the "completeness" of the border. It doesn't look like it's flash, so how?

Also I know how to animate using GSAP.
Is there anyway to replicate this using GSAP? or something you can recommend?

Comment: I normally make a gif as an background. I dont know about them tho

Comment: You can achieve this with SVG, see [codepen](http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/kyGqm).

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996110/progress-bar-along-the-borders-of-a-rectangle/32003052#32003052. I have closed it as dupe (even though the end points are different from that website) but you can get the idea of how to implement it from the linked answer. It has both CSS and SVG versions.